# Scale UITabBarItem BackgroundImage to size of the Item

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITabBar, but at Runtime I dont know how many tabs will appear.

Now I customize the UITabBar Images, and have the problem that the Image always scales in its actual Image Size, However I want it to scale always to the size of the UITabBar Item it is set as background of.

[image]

I set the background images like this:

```
-(void)addTabBarItems{
  UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tab1" image:nil tag:1];
  UITabBarItem *item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tab2" image:nil tag:2];
  UITabBarItem *item3 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tab3" image:nil tag:3];
  UITabBarItem *item4 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tab3" image:nil tag:4];

  [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarItemBackground.png"]];

  NSArray *tabBarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1,item2,item3,item4, nil];
  self.tabBar.items = tabBarItems;
}
```

I found this line by researching, but it doesn't work (example item1):

```
item1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10,0,-10,0);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, use setitems: animated:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_21

Then access the individual tabbaritems frame

```
[[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] frame];
```

(Thought about including this in my answer, wish I had)

Comment: I know how to set the TabBarItems, but I dont know how to scale the image to the size of the UITabBarItem.